# Does an AES encrypted string include | (pipe)?

Tags: c#, aes, rijndaelmanaged

I'm using .NET's RijndaelManaged class to encrypt and decrypt strings. 3 different strings are first encrypted and then concatenated, separated by a pipe (|), and then this string is saved back to the database.

When I need to decrypt the string, I first separate the three encrypted strings and then decrypt them.

I'm concatenating the individual encrypted strings as follows:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.Append(Crypto.Encrypt("string1")).Append("|")
.Append(Crypto.Encrypt("string2")).Append("|")
          Crypto.Encrypt("string3"));
```

My question is:
When encrypting a string using RijndaelManaged, can the encrypted string include the pipe sign?

Comment: Oh wait your mean add it on after the encryption?

Comment: Could you create a link to that `Encrypt` method you are calling? I can not directly find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm using .NET's RijndaelManaged class to encrypt and decrypt strings.

You may be using that as the *underlying* encryption - but RijndaelManaged only deals with binary data, as is normally the case with encryption code.

So presumably you're converting your string into bytes (hopefully using a sensible encoding such as UTF-8), then encrypting, then converting the encrypted bytes back into a string.

Without knowing *how* you're converting the encrypted bytes back into a string, we can't possibly know whether the results will include a `|`. If you're using [`Convert.ToBase64String`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.tobase64string.aspx) (which is probably what I'd use) you'll be fine, as `|` isn't used within the normal base64 alphabet. Ditto if you're just converting each byte into two hex digits. But maybe you're doing something else. (If you're using `Encoding`, you're doing it wrong by the way, and can easily lose data.)

Comment: I'm using this exact same code: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rijndaelmanaged.aspx

Comment: @Ivan-MarkDebono: Well that encrypts a string to *bytes*, not to a string. So how can you "concatenate" them with a `|`? It sounds like you've got the extra step of converting from bytes to a string, but you haven't told us how.